# Code with datetime module not working as expected

Tags: python

I am facing a problem with the following code:

```
# Creating a timer

from datetime import date, timedelta 
from datetime import datetime

try:
    secondsTicker = int(input("Enter the number of seconds to wait: "))

except:
    print("Invalid value !... Defaulting to 5 seconds")
    secondsTicker = 5
    
timeShift = timedelta(seconds=secondsTicker)

# Current system time

currentTime = datetime.now()
endTime = currentTime + timeShift

# Start a loop and check if 5 seconds has passed

while True:
    if datetime.now() == endTime:
        print(f"{timeShift} seconds has passed since {currentTime} and is now {endTime}")
        break
    
    # print(f"{(endTime-datetime.now()).total_seconds()} has passed")
```

The above code is a random idea of mine to just create a timer. The loop is where I am facing problems. If I leave the last line commented it runs as I expect it to and prints the message inside the if-statement when the condition is met. However I wanted to include a message that is printed to the screen to keep me updated on the time that has passed, but when I ran it again with the last line uncommented it did not break after the amount of seconds I specified and the program continued to run and even said negative seconds has passed.

Is there a better way to implement this perhaps using another module?

Comment: Note that this code will use all the CPU available to it just to sit around and do nothing. To implement a timer consider using the threading library. E.g. [`threading.Timer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#timer-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the line

```py
if datetime.now() == endTime:
```

Notice that a `datetime` has (at least) microsecond precision. So if that line is not executed at **exactly** `endTime`, the condition will never be true, hence the program runs forever.

Change it to

```py
if datetime.now() >= endTime:
```

to avoid this problem.

Comment: As a side note: You may want to do some reading on "monotonic time". The program as currently written does not work if `datetime.now()` is on an airplane which passes through timezones...

Comment: Thank you for your assistance the code now works as I wished it did. I shall read on monotonic time as well

Comment: @AliasQLD, if this question is answered then please accept it as answered so it becomes dequeued.